# How to draw grid lines fir every ticks?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have x axis with 10 ticks. I would like to draw a grid line for each tick. My try is here:

```
const dataSet = [
  0,
  10,
  20,
  30,
  40,
  50,
  60,
  70,
  80,
  90,
  100
];

const w = 1200;
const h = 250;
const padding = 20;
const paddingYaxis = 50;

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0,100])
               .range([paddingYaxis, w - 10]);

const svg = d3.select('#costSquareGraph');

svg.selectAll('line')
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()   
  .append('line')
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return xScale(d); })
  .attr("y1", padding)
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return xScale(d); })
  .attr("y2", h - padding)
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("stroke", "#999");     

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                .tickSizeOuter(-10)
                .tickPadding(5);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (h - padding) + ')')
  .call(xAxis);
```

Live demo [is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/xfbjnypr/15/)

But my code has a problem. When the number of labels increment - I'll have to write code for a new line. Its very bad practice.

I need cycle for draw all possible grid lines. Please help me.

PS: i use D3 5.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing grid lines can be done using the [tickSizeInner](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickSizeInner) method of the axis. You don't need to specifically draw the grid lines as you do in your code.

Example:

```
d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeInner(-height)
```

In your case, to include the padding, the above will change to:

```
d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeInner(-(h-padding))
```

**Snippet:**

```js
const dataSet = [
  0,
  10,
  20,
  30,
  40,
  50,
  60,
  70,
  80,
  90,
  100
];

const w = 1200;
const h = 250;
const padding = 20;
const paddingYaxis = 50;

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0,100])
               .range([paddingYaxis, w - 10]);

const svg = d3.select('#costSquareGraph');  

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                .tickSizeInner(-(h-padding))
                .tickPadding(5);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (h - padding) + ')')
  .call(xAxis);
  //.selectAll('.tick line').attr('y1', 3);
```

```css
svg {
 width: 100%;

}

.tick line {
  stroke: #CCC;
}
.cost-square-wrap {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>


    <div class="cost-square-wrap">
   <svg id="costSquareGraph" viewbox="0 0 1200 250"></svg> 
  </div>
```

This just changes the `y2` of the tick lines and of course it'll match the number of ticks as well.

Let's say I change the number of ticks = 20 by `.ticks(20)`. Snippet:

```js
const dataSet = [
  0,
  10,
  20,
  30,
  40,
  50,
  60,
  70,
  80,
  90,
  100
];

const w = 1200;
const h = 250;
const padding = 20;
const paddingYaxis = 50;

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0,100])
               .range([paddingYaxis, w - 10]);

const svg = d3.select('#costSquareGraph');  

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                .tickSizeInner(-(h-padding))
                .tickPadding(5).ticks(20);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (h - padding) + ')')
  .call(xAxis);
  //.selectAll('.tick line').attr('y1', 3);
```

```css
svg {
 width: 100%;

}

.tick line {
  stroke: #CCC;
}
.cost-square-wrap {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>


    <div class="cost-square-wrap">
   <svg id="costSquareGraph" viewbox="0 0 1200 250"></svg> 
  </div>
```

Added some CSS as well:

```
.tick line {
   stroke: #CCC;
}
```

Hope this helps.